# Oracle SYS.ILOxxx indexes created automatically even though there is no LOB object

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, lob

During creation of tables in OracleDB there are indexes connnected with table created automatically. They are LOB indexes as SYS.ILOxxx. What is the reason? How to delete those indexes?

```
    create table test_table (
    very_long_title varchar2 (1500 char)
);
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete CREATE TABLE statement as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please

Comment: Which schema are the tables being created in? SYS?

Comment: no, in other schema

Comment: Not surprisingly that statement didn't create any indexes when I ran it on my local instance. Unfortunately we can't explain why your database is apparently doing this weird thing if you can't provide a reproducible test case. The lessons on history are that the database actually isn't doing this weird thing but there's some missing piece of information which would allow you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

Your table is using an [extended data type.](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/extended-data-types-12cR1)  When you ask for `1500 char` with a UTF8 character set, each character could use up to 4 bytes, which means you're really asking for a 6,000 byte column.  For strings over 4,000 bytes Oracle secretly uses LOBs to store the data.  LOBs are stored in a separate segment from the table, and need an index to access their values.

So while Oracle supports 32K bytes of data for a VARCHAR2, they kind of cheated, and you will run into these weird issues.

This issue may not be reproducible for others because if their MAX_STRING_SIZE is set to STANDARD, the `1500 char` will max out at a smaller size and not use LOBs.

```
select value
from v$parameter
where name like 'max_string_size';
```

Comment: Thanks Jon! What do you suggest? Should I get rid off this extended data type? 
Now, I will need to divide length of some attributes  per 4 to be consistent with other instances of database. Can I easily turn it off? Should I?

Comment: @devninja That's a tough question and I'm not sure what to recommend.  Enabling extended data types is difficult, and as far as I know there's no going back, so I assume someone at your organization chose that option.  You may want to speak to your DBAs.  If you have multiple databases, and the behavior is different between them, that can certainly be a problem a DBA should care about.  The indexes themselves are weird, but shouldn't be breaking anything.  This might be one of those things you just have to learn to ignore.

Comment: Thanks for help! This was the answer I was looking for